# Select foreign key from table where one of the column's value in all rows with same foreign key are greater than given value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called pres_marriage which has all US president's marriages and the columns it has are:

- pres_id(int, foreign key)
- spouse_name(varchar)
- spouse_age(int)
- nr_children(int)
- marriage_year(int)

I wanted to select all presidents who have married wives only older than 30, but what I tried was

```
select pres_id
from pres_marriage
where spouse_age > 30;
```

but then if that president had married someone younger than 30 it'll just ignore that row and still give me his id.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
select pres_id
from pres_marriage
group by pres_id
having MIN(spouse_age) > 30;
```